# get gmt time two hours ago Python 2.7

Tags: python, time, timedelta, gmt

Hi I am having trouble getting the time two hours ago in a similar function to my get_timestamp =>

```
def get_timestamp():
    """Return correctly formatted timestamp"""
    return strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", gmtime())
def two_hours_ago():
    """Return correctly formatted timestamp"""
    last = (date.today() - timedelta(hours=1))
    return strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", gmtime()-'2HOURS')
```

I tried this:

```
def two_hours_ago():
    """Return correctly formatted timestamp"""
    today = date.today()
    yesterday = (today - timedelta(hours=2))
    print(yesterday.timetuple())
    return strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", yesterday.timetuple())
```

UPDATE
thank you 
Huang Yen Hao

I was looking for a 2 hour interval returned in ISO format for Amazon MWS, I used the following functions to return the correctly formatted time.

```
def two_hours_ago():
    """Return correctly formatted timestamp"""
    now = datetime.now()
    two_hours_ago = (now - timedelta(hours=2))
    return two_hours_ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
def now():
    """Return correctly formatted timestamp"""
    now = datetime.now()
    two_hours_ago = (now - timedelta(hours=0))
    return two_hours_ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

Comment: A `date` object don't have time. So `today - timedelta(hours=2)` is a non-sense.

Comment: If you want to work with UTC date and time, you can use `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`.

Comment: _I tried this_ What did it do, and how did it not meet your expectations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand the code that is `today = date.today()`.

Is it means, for example, 2017/10/18 00:00:00?

The following code can get time two hours ago. I am not sure what you what is it or not..

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def two_hours_ago():
    """Return correctly formatted timestamp"""
    now = datetime.now()
    two_hours_ago = (now - timedelta(hours=2))
    return two_hours_ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

For this code, it will perform like following

```
>>> two_hours_ago()
'2017-10-19T11:28:40Z'
```

Comment: thank you! I was originally working with datetime, I didn't catch that. I have updated my answer.